# How to get/set pipeline spec by REST API limited to a project?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines, openshift-pipelines

I'm pretty new to Openshift and Tekton--we have an Openshift server (cluster?) with pipelines and I'm trying to get/create/update the Pipelines, Tasks, PipelineRuns, etc. via REST API.

Using the API browser in Openshift I've found that the API group for the pipelines is `operator.tekton.dev/v1alpha1`. I was able to pull a get request from that endpoint and in the response under `resources` I can see `tektonpipelines` and `tektonpipelines/status`, however when I try to get a request against those endpoints (e.g. `operator.tekton.dev/v1alpha1/tektonpipelines`) I get basically access denied:

```
tektonpipelines.operator.tekton.dev is forbidden: User \u0022myuser\u0022 cannot list resource \u0022tektonpipelines\u0022 in API group \u0022operator.tekton.dev\u0022 at the cluster scope
```

I created a pipeline from the GUI under a project I created--I don't need to access all pipelines in the cluster, just the one(s) under my project.

Referencing the [Openshift API](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.5/html-single/using_the_openshift_rest_api/index#listing-a-specific-project) as well as the [Tekton API](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipeline-api/#tekton.dev/v1.PipelineSpec) documentation, I can't figure out how I would get/put/etc a pipeline, task, etc under a specific project? Is this possible?

Or do I need to request elevated permissions to get results under the cluster scope (which I doubt will be approved)?